# Anvil for mac showing apache root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, apache

I was running Anvil for Mac (http://anvilformac.com) to help run my rails apps on my dev laptop. It worked great, until I upgraded to Yosemite beta. Now when I try to open my site from the Anvil interface, it shows the default Apache "It works!" notice rather than loading the rails app.

Any thoughts? There's very few config options to play with in the Anvil app. I did try re-installing both `Pow` and Anvil.app, with no changes.

Thanks